# Почему метод format() выдает ошибку?

Tags: python-3.x

```
SUFFIXES = {1000: ['KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
            1024: ['KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB', 'EiB', 'ZiB', 'YiB']}
si_suffixes = []
si_suffixes.extend(SUFFIXES[1000])
si_suffixes +=['BA']


print(type(SUFFIXES))
print(type(si_suffixes))
print(SUFFIXES)
#
print('1000{0[0]} = 1{0[1]}'.format(si_suffixes))
# si_suffixes список Почему метод format() выдает ошибку?
print('1000{[0]} = 1{[1]}'.format(si_suffixes))
```

Comment: А что должно быть? Точнее что Вы пытаетесь получить из этой конструкции `{[0]}`?

Comment: Мне интересно почему нужно обратиться по индексу как к словарю, а не как списку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Структура **[0]** - является **индексом** (*элементом*) какого-то из типов данных, которые поддерживают индексирование (*списки, кортежи, строки...*). То есть перед извлечением элемента должны обязательно идти данные. У Вас этого нет.
2. Так как Вы передаёте один список на две позиции, как я понял, то Вам нужно обозначить это следующим образом `{0} {0}`.
3. Если вы хотите получить первую букву элементов списка, то примените ещё один индекс, к элементу списка.

   print('1000{0[0][0]} = 1{0[1][0]}'.format(si_suffixes))

P.S. Так устроен питон (та и не только питон), что обращаться к элементам списка нужно по индексу. А к элементам словаря - по ключу.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!